# How to check for some specfic values in web.config using powershell

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell

I am trying to work around finding some specific lines/values in web.config but not sure how to do that. For example if there is a line

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0"/>
```

how to write a script to find this line in the web.config file also if the values are correct for specific environment

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Select-XML, do a `select -expand Node`, and then a `Where{$_.Key -eq "webpages:Version"}` to specify your specific node. It would look something like this:

```
Select-XML -Path C:\Path\To\web.config -XPath "//add" | Select -ExpandProperty Node | Where{$_.Key -eq "webpages:Version"}
```

That will output:

```
key                                                value
---                                                -----
webpages:Version                                   2.0.0.0
```

Or you can get-content into a variable and use -XML $Variable instead of -Path C:\Path\To\file.xml. Like:

```
[XML]$WebConfig = Get-Content C:\Path\To\web.config
Select-XML -XML $WebConfig -XPath "//add" | Select -ExpandProperty Node | Where{$_.Key -eq "webpages:Version"}
```